# Inserting data to multiple table with selecting from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

> I have 3 table and want to insert records on first 2 table based on
>   number of records on table3.
>
> My Table1_ID column inside the table 2 links with table1 ID.
>
> There are 8 records in table3 so need to insert this 8 records inside
>   the table2 Name column, same time I need to insert data to table1.
>   In table1 if you notice position starts with 0 on fieldID 50 in the
>   result table

**table1**

```
|ID|FieldID|Position|
|0 |   0   |   0    |
|1 |   15  |   1    |
|2 |   15  |   2    |
```

**table2**

```
|ID|Table1_ID|  Y/N   | Name |
|0 |   0     |   1    | N1   |
|1 |   1     |   1    | N2   |
|2 |   2     |   1    | N3   |
```

**table3**

```
|ID| Name | 
|1 |      |
|2 | N4   |
|3 | N5   | 
|4 | N6   |
|5 | N7   |
|6 | N8   | 
|7 | N9   |
|8 | N10  |
|9 | N11  |
```

result

**table1**

```
|ID|FieldID|Position|
|0 |   0   |   0    |
|1 |   15  |   0    |
|2 |   15  |   1    |
|3 |   50  |   0    |
|4 |   50  |   1    |
|5 |   50  |   2    |
|6 |   50  |   3    |
|7 |   50  |   4    |
|8 |   50  |   5    |
|9 |   50  |   6    |
|10|   50  |   7    |
```

**table2**

```
|ID|Table1_ID|  Y/N   | Name |
|0 |   0     |   1    | N1   |
|1 |   1     |   1    | N2   |
|2 |   2     |   1    | N3   |
|3 |   3     |   1    | N4   |
|4 |   4     |   1    | N5   |
|5 |   5     |   1    | N6   |
|6 |   6     |   1    | N7   |
|7 |   7     |   1    | N8   |
|8 |   8     |   1    | N9   |
|9 |   9     |   1    | N10  |
|10|   10    |   1    | N11  |
```

Comment: How do I know `FieldID` is 50? I don't see that anywhere in your `table3`.

Comment: this 50 comes manually. not coming in any other table. Need to populate the table1 with static value which is 50.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have a design problem here rather than anything else. You may want to consider redesigning your table structures before you move any further.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that the question is how to insert to both tables together, then either :

1) open a transaction, perform both inserts, and then commit the data changes. As far as any other session will be concerned both tables would have been updated together.

2) Use the OUTPUT option in sql-server.  While inserting into table2, add the OUTPUT option to insert data into table1. See link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best approach to getting your desired output, but here is what you could do to (`NOT RECOMMENDED`):

**CREATE TABLES:**

```
create table table1 (ID int identity(0,1), 
                     FieldID int, 
                     Position int
               CONSTRAINT pk_table1_id PRIMARY KEY(ID));

insert into table1 values
(0 ,0),
(15,1),
(15,2);

create table table2 (ID int identity(0,1), 
                     Table1_ID int,  
                     Y_N  int, 
                     Name varchar(50) 
              CONSTRAINT fk_table1_pid FOREIGN KEY(Table1_ID)REFERENCES table1(ID));

insert into table2 values
(0, 1, 'N1'),
(1, 1, 'N2'),
(2, 1, 'N3');

create table table3 (ID int, Name varchar(50));

insert into table3 values
(1,  null),  
(2, 'N4'),
(3, 'N5'), 
(4, 'N6'),
(5, 'N7'),
(6, 'N8'), 
(7, 'N9'),
(8, 'N10'),
(9, 'N11');


insert into table1 (FieldID,Position)
select 50 as FieldID,
       1 as Position
from table3
where name is not null;

insert into table2 (Table1_ID,Y_N,Name)
select [id] + 1 as Table1_ID,
       1 as Y_N,
       Name
from table3
where name is not null;
```

**UPDATE Position in TABLE1:**

```
UPDATE t
SET position = t1.rn
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  id,
            row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY FieldID ORDER BY ID
            ) - 1 AS rn
    FROM table1 
    ) t1 ON t.id = t1.id;
```

**SELECT FROM TABLES:**

```
select * from table1;

select * from table2;
```

**Results:**

**Table1**

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID | FieldID | Position |
+----+---------+----------+
|  0 |       0 |        0 |
|  1 |      15 |        0 |
|  2 |      15 |        1 |
|  3 |      50 |        0 |
|  4 |      50 |        1 |
|  5 |      50 |        2 |
|  6 |      50 |        3 |
|  7 |      50 |        4 |
|  8 |      50 |        5 |
|  9 |      50 |        6 |
| 10 |      50 |        7 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

**Table2**

```
+----+-----------+-----+------+
| ID | Table1_ID | Y_N | Name |
+----+-----------+-----+------+
|  0 |         0 |   1 | N1   |
|  1 |         1 |   1 | N2   |
|  2 |         2 |   1 | N3   |
|  3 |         3 |   1 | N4   |
|  4 |         4 |   1 | N5   |
|  5 |         5 |   1 | N6   |
|  6 |         6 |   1 | N7   |
|  7 |         7 |   1 | N8   |
|  8 |         8 |   1 | N9   |
|  9 |         9 |   1 | N10  |
| 10 |        10 |   1 | N11  |
+----+-----------+-----+------+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70d37/7/1)

Again, this will work for the output above, but there are too many design flaws here. Hence, the reason for the post update and all the extra stuffs. Hopefully, you could redesign your table structures so you can avoid all the nuisances.